# ExePackage SourceFile is copied to development folder

Tags: sql-server, wix, burn

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850462/how-to-create-a-wix-exepackage-that-only-has-a-download-link) indicates that when an ExePackage has DownloadUrl it also needs a copy of SourceFile.

We keep the copy of the Sql Server Setup in a separate Release folder that is not part of the development environment. We do this so our daily backup doesn't have to copy the same 300+MB every time.

However, when Burn builds our Setup, it copies the SourceFile to the output folder along with the .exe it creates. The filename is the DisplayName and the file is the same size as the file in the Release folder.

The result is similar to setting CopyLocal on a project reference.

Can I tell Burn not to copy this file on build?

Edit

I am deleting the file with the post-build event in Visual Studio. However, this doesn't answer the original question.

Further Information

After I delete the file and run the Setup, I get an error in the MSI log: Failed to resolve source for file.

This happens at run-time, and the file referenced is located in the project output folder. How is it possible that Burn is looking at the source file at run-time?

Answer (score 1):

That question also mentioned that it if you provide the `RemotePayload` element, then it doesn't need the SourceFile.  So use `RemotePayload` so that it never copies it.

Comment: Thanks Sean. I will try that. Does this mean that I cannot tell Burn not to copy the file?